# I have a catalog of 24 items, when one item is clicked, I want to hide 23 items and show more information on the selected item

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

This sounds much simpler than it is.  I cannot amend the DOM using jQuery because each item and its details are populated from a database using PHP.

What I want to do in theory is so simple yet I cannot accomplish it.  For example what i want is:

If item 1001 is clicked then hide all other items and show more detailed information on item 1001.

This is the second time that I have looked for assistance in this matter, it seems nobody has the answer to this problem.  I have rephrased my question and am trying again and would really appreciate an help at all.  Even if you can just point me in the right direction and i will go an research it.  TBH i have absolutely no idea where to begin.

Thanks

```
<script>
        $(".1001").click(function(){
            $("#images1").remove();
            $("#images2").show();
        });
     </script>


     <section class="catalogListing">
     <?php $load_content->load_content("1001");?>
      <div class="dresses">
       <a class="1001" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?><br />Was:<strike>£175.00</strike></p>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>  
      </div>
     </section>

     <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1002");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?><br />Was:<strike>£150.00</strike></p>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
       <p class="p4"><font>Out of stock</font></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1003");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?><br />Was:<strike>£150.00</strike></p>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
       <p class="p4"><font>Out of stock</font></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1004");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>

     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1005");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?><br />Was:<strike>£150.00</strike></p>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1006");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1007");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1008");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
       <p class="p4"><font>Out of stock</font></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1009");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    </section><!---End of first nine items--->

    <section id="secondNineItems">

   <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1010");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1011");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1012");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1013");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>


    <!---Items with the class "tunics" are below--->

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1014");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1015");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>


    <!---Items with the class "tops" are below--->

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1016");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
      <p class="p4"><font>Out of stock</font></p> 
     </div>
    </section>          

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1017");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1018");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
      <p class="p4"><font>Out of stock</font></p> 
     </div>
    </section>

    </section><!---End of second nine items--->

    <section id="thirdNineItems">

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1019");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1020");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1021");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1022");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1023");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p>
     </div>
    </section>

    <section class="catalogListing">
      <div class="dresses">
      <?php $load_content->load_content("1024");?>
       <a class="a3" href="#">
       <figure><img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgMedium();?>" /></figure>
       <p class="listing"><?php echo $load_content->getTitle();?></p></a>
       <p class="listingSub">Artist:<?php echo $load_content->getArtist();?>
       <p class="p4"><strong>Now: £<span class="price"><?php echo $load_content->getPrice();?></span></strong></p> 
      <p class="p4"><font>Out of stock</font></p> 
     </div>
    </section>

    </section><!---End of third nine items--->

    </article><!---End of article:ShopContent--->

   </article><!---End of article:ShopWrapper--->


  </article><!---End of article:main--->

  <!---Main Content Area clothes--->

  <article id="clothes1">



    <p class="p2"><a href="index.php" class="a2">HOME&nbsp;></a>&nbsp;<a href="shop.php" class="a2">SHOP&nbsp;></a>&nbsp;<strong>CLOTHES 1</strong></p>

    <!--- Load images --->
    <section id="images1" style="width:400px; float:left; height:auto;">

    <p><?php $load_content->load_content('1002');?></p>

     <a href="<?php echo $load_content->getImgLarge1();?>" class="zoom">
     <img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgLarge1();?>" width="375" height="568" alt="arrows"></a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall1();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall2();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall3();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall4();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>     

    </section>

    <!--- Load images --->
    <section id="images2" style="width:400px; float:left; height:auto;">

    <p><?php $load_content->load_content('1001');?></p>

     <a href="<?php echo $load_content->getImgLarge1();?>" class="zoom">
     <img src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgLarge1();?>" width="375" height="568" alt="arrows"></a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall1();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall2();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall3();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>

     <a href="#">
     <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="<?php echo $load_content->getImgSmall4();?>" width="64" height="100"/>
     </a>     

    </section>
```

PHP generated HTML code:

```
<section id="images2" style="width:400px; float:left; height:auto;">

<p></p>

 <a href="images/Catalog/Largest/aof_14102_amorous_arrows.jpg" class="zoom">
 <img src="images/Catalog/Largest/aof_14102_amorous_arrows.jpg" width="375" height="568" alt="arrows"></a>

 <a href="#">
 <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="images/Catalog/Small/aof_14102_amorous_arrows.jpg" width="64" height="100">
 </a>

 <a href="#">
 <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="images/Catalog/Small/aof_14175_amorous_arrows_side_back_view.jpg" width="64" height="100">
 </a>

 <a href="#">
 <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="images/Catalog/Small/aof_14077_amorous_arrows_other_view.jpg" width="64" height="100">
 </a>

 <a href="#">
 <img class="thumbnails" title="Click to enlarge" src="images/Catalog/Small/amorous_arrows.jpg" width="64" height="100">
 </a>     

</section>
```

Comment: Can you give some code of what you've done so far. Or a little fiddle?

Comment: There are a thousand ways to solve this, so it's hard to point you in a right direction. For what it's worth, AngularJS has a pretty decent tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: I started out similar and for that reason I've actually upvoted. SO users can be harsh to Noobs, but once you learn to ask good quality questions with code or a jsfiddle, then things start looking up!

Comment: why can't you amend the dom? ajax request to fetch data about the clicked item, stuff it into the dom, hide the other items. not particularly hard or involved... JS doesn't know and couldn't care less if the html it's working on came from a database or was written out by hand by scratching bits into a harddrive platter.

Comment: Also if it is populated from a DB why can you not use jQuery? Surely you are only hiding it to the user on the front-end?

Comment: When i try to hide it, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Create all the list items with a special css class like 'hideable' in their outermost divs.

Load up all the items, and include the'more details' data in a separate div with a style property `'visibility: hidden'`.

When one item is checked, use jQuery to select all the items with a class 'hideable' and cycle through them, setting their visibility to *hidden*.

Finally set visibility to *visible* on the clicked item AND it's 'more data' div.

Comment: I already have.
  $(".1001").click(function(){
  $("#images1").hide();
  $("#images2").show();
  });

Comment: @ChrisBrennan did you see any error or something in console ? Maybe jquery is not loaded or there's no such element that is selector trying to address.

Comment: No errors, jquery is loaded fine and the element is correct.  It just wont hide.  Yet I have done this countless time, but once i incorporate PHP it no longer works

Comment: It's sure not the PHP that's affecting jQuery .. they live in different worlds. Does it work on pure raw html and jQuery ?

Comment: @ChrisBrennan can you post html that is generated by php. Maybe there's some problem or something. It'll be clear for others to understand the cause.

Comment: Just what I was about to ask too ... In fact the code is extremely long-winded so it's difficult to keep a track on what's happening scrolling up and down ... a couple of nested loops should make it all so much easier to read .. and to debug ... my bet is that `<?php $load_content->load_content('1xxx');?>` isn't returning a valid HTML snippet

Comment: It is, i have pasted the generated html into my question at the top. - thanks

Comment: OK @ChrisBrennan .. I think the other guys are already ahead of me in terms of what I ws thinking to do ... Just ignore this answer and go with the others ...

Answer (score 0):

Basic premise is this, you're going to hide all items but the one clicked, you're also going to show more info for the one clicked. You can do this with basic show/hide jQuery functionality.

Load the more info divs and set their display to none then toggle those when a particular item is clicked.

Very basic, very ugly version here: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/zf5ZT/

```
$('div').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('smallDiv'))
    {
       $('div').not(this).fadeOut();
       $(this).addClass('bigDiv'); 
       $(this).removeClass('smallDiv'); 
        $('.info').fadeIn();
    } else {        
       $('div').not(this).fadeIn();
       $(this).addClass('smallDiv'); 
       $(this).removeClass('bigDiv');  
        $('.info').fadeOut();
    }
});



.smallDiv{width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#CCC;border:1px solid #333;margin: 10px;cursor:pointer;}
.bigDiv{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#CCC;border:1px solid #333;margin: 10px;cursor:pointer;}
.info{display:none;}


<div id="1" class="smallDiv"><div class="info">This is some text</div></div>
<div id="2" class="smallDiv"></div>
<div id="3" class="smallDiv"></div>
<div id="4" class="smallDiv"></div>
```

You should be able to adjust this to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty difficult to answer without seeing any of your code... but something kinda like this might do the trick.

...roughly, the markup...

```
<a href="#" class='view-details-btn' data-product='product1001'>View Details</a>
<div class='item-container' data-product='product1001'>
 <!-- stuff goes in here -->
</div>
```

...and js...

```
function details(switch,clicked){

    var objects = $('.item-container'),
        objectToShow = $('.item-container[data-product=' + $(clicked).attr('data-product') + ']'),
        objectsToHide = $(objects).not(objectToShow);

    if (switch === 'show'){
        $(objectsToHide).hide();
        $(objectToShow).addClass('show-details');
    } else {
        $(objects).removeClass('show-details').show();
    }   
}

$('a.view-details-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    details('show',$(this));
});

$('a.hide-details-btn')..click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    details('hide');
});
```

... and css...

```
.item-container .detailbox {display: none;}
.item-container.show-details .detailbox {display: block;}
```

Would probably need to fine-tune some of that for specifically how your markup it arranged, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $all_listings = $('section.catalogListing');    

$('section.catalogListing').click(function(){

    var $listing = $(this);

    if(!$listing.hasClass('active') {
        $all_listings.removeClass('active').hide();
        $listing.addClass('active').show();
    } else {
     $all_listings.show();
     $listing.removeClass('active');
    }

});
```

How does that work for you bud?

**Explanation:**

Add or Remove active class depending on if it is 'on' or 'off'.
Only show the the listing which is active, however if clicking on a listing which is already active, then remove its active class and display everything....back to square one basically.

Use active class on the top parent - which is the section in this case - but in your CSS you may want to hide and show item details depending on the active class.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I want.  This block of code, simply filtered my catalog dependent on what item was selected.  What i want is similar.  My site is at http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00448232/COM601/assignment_1/jquery_demos.html

Comment: Could you go to it an log in then click on the first item in the catalog.  You will see that the page generated is what I want to achieve for each item.  I have done this statically as an example, but how can i get it so as this is the outcome if any item is selected (but obviously showing their images/details instead) if you get me.

Comment: You've got a range of options here mate. You could remove hide and show in favour of some CSS based on the class (opacity for example?), or use other jQuery effects. Let me know if you have anything specific in mind and I can try point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have nothing specific in mind and dont really care about animate or effects.  I simply just want all items to be hidden except the clicked one but then change the layout of the page and show additional info.  DId you log in and view the catalog to see what im trying to achieve?